# I am trying to execute custom yolov5 object detection model. I am facing following error

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, yolo, yolov5

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Bhavesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\multiprocessing\reductions.py", line 36, in **del**
File "C:\Users\Bhavesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\storage.py", line 520, in _free_weak_ref
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_free_weak_ref'
**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_free_weak_ref'**

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens more frequently when you are running out of CPU, I think you are  running your model on CPU maybe try to switch **to GPU if you have a big dataset or make sure the batch size fits your CPU if your dataset isn't that big**. Sometimes this problem can disappear if some processes are done.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this AttributeError is related to pytorch not with yolov5.
Based on the comments on [this Github thread](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/74016), it is resolved by downgrading pytorch version. However, this AttributeError has no impact on training and saving the data/model to the disk. Everything works fine with the training and model

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I fixed it by deleting the c:\users\MyUser.cache\torch folder and running the project again, this reinstalls the dependencies.
I hope it helps you